# can't find /home/username/Box in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Tags: mount

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://aarongriffith.net/2014/08/mount-box-cloud-storage-in-ubuntu/) to mount Box.com on my Ubuntu machine. It works great up until the last step:

```
mount ~/Box
```

Which spits out there error:

```
can't find /home/username/Box in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

This directory does exist, though. I can navigate to it with `~/Box`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of your /etc/fstab file

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the problem. I'd misread the instructions and put the a line that should have been in fstab in secrets. Thanks again for the prompt response!

Comment: Could you add your solution below?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I misread the tutorial. To get this working, open `/etc/fstab` and add:

```
https://dav.box.com/dav /home/<username>/Box  davfs  _netdev,rw,user 0 0
```